# passing nonce to server and back to Braintree SDK

Tags: ruby-on-rails, braintree

The following view is generating a proper nonce as evidenced by the alert in the javascript code.

```
<div class='row'>
  <div class='small-12 columns text-center'>
    <h4><%= t('proceed_to_payment') %> <%= number_to_currency(@clientorder.payment_amount) %></h4>
    <% if !@clientorder.paid? %>
      <%= form_tag transacted_clientorders_path(id: @clientorder.id), id: 'checkout' do %>
        <input type="hidden" id="nonce" name="payment_method_nonce" />
        <div id='dropin-container'></div>
        <%= submit_tag t('submit'), id: 'submit-button' %>
      <% end %>
      <script>
        $.ajax({
          method: "POST",
          url: "/transacted?id=<%= @clientorder.id %>&locale=<%= I18n.locale %>",
          data: { payment_method_nonce: payload.nonce }
        })
      </script>
      <script>
        var button = document.querySelector('#submit-button');
        braintree.dropin.create({
          authorization: "<%= @client_token %>",
          container: '#dropin-container'
          }, function (createErr, instance) {
            button.addEventListener('click', function () {
              instance.requestPaymentMethod(function (err, payload) {
                alert(payload.nonce);
                console.log(payload.nonce);
                console.log(err);
                if (err) {
                  console.log('Error', err);
                  return;
                }
             // Add the nonce to the form and submit
               document.querySelector('#nonce').value = payload.nonce;
               form.submit();
             });
            });
          });
      </script>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

the controller action

```
  def transacted
    @result = Braintree::Transaction.sale(
      amount:  @clientorder.payment_amount,
      payment_method_nonce: params[:payment_method_nonce], 
      options: {
        submit_for_settlement: true},
      )
    if @result.transaction.status == "submitted_for_settlement"
      [...]
```

however does not lead to any further action. `@result`is nil as an nonce is not being submitted, and in practice the amount also in not being passed for the following are the request parameters logged.

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"qXjwFuI4mNRM+ZFoQ5TwvUBv58fLNVJyQVHJm/FfBdIaArbfhjJP0WirTe+7FnSl+/asJ+fY+d+JPA7xKNLP6Q==",
 "payment_method_nonce"=>"",
 "commit"=>"Submit",
 "id"=>"4",
 "locale"=>"en"}
```

where has this strayed from the proper path?

Comment: Where is your API code stored? and what does your create action look like? I noticed that is your create.  What's your routes look like for that transaction method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things wrong.

1. The ajax call in that position does not get the nonce to handle
2. Set up this way, there are going to be 2 calls to the server: the ajax call and the form call itself
3. The consequence of item 2 is that the form call will have an empty nonce and thus will generate `!result.success?` and thus a hash of `result.errors` which should be eventually handled.

Thus,

```
<div class='row'>
<div class='small-12 columns text-center'>
  <div id="dropin-container"></div>
  <button id="submit-button" class='button success'><%= t('proceed_to_payment') %> <%= number_to_currency(@clientorder.payment_amount) %></button>
  <script>
    var button = document.querySelector('#submit-button');

    braintree.dropin.create({
      authorization: '<%= @client_token %>',
      container: '#dropin-container'
    }, function (createErr, instance) {
      button.addEventListener('click', function () {
        instance.requestPaymentMethod(function (err, payload) {
          // Submit payload.nonce to your server
        $.ajax({
          method: "POST",
          url: "<%= transacted_clientorders_path(id: @clientorder.id, locale: I18n.locale) %>",
          data: { payment_method_nonce: payload.nonce }
        })
        if (err) {
          console.log('Error', err);
          return;
        }
           // Add the nonce to the form and submit
                document.querySelector('#nonce').value = payload.nonce;
                form.submit();
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
```